# Linq Query to Get Column Names

Tags: sql, linq

This brings the column names of Person table:

```
var query = from t in typeof(Person).GetProperties() select t.Name;
```

How can I parametrize the typeof's argument. Like:

```
string tableName="Employee";
var query = from t in typeof(tableName).GetProperties() select t.Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which takes a string parameter

```
var query = from t in Type.GetType(tableName).GetProperties() select t.Name;
```

BTW you should pass type's [`fully qualified name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to this method.That means you should specify `namespace` + `class name`.

Comment: NullReferenceException!

Comment: @Jude try to specify namespace name + class name.Like `MyEntities.Employee`

Comment: Didn't make it happen! I think it's me. Fully qualified name didn't work either!

Comment: Apparently, GetType requires the instance. It works like Employee e = new Employee(); e.GetType()...